# Count and sum up data in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi everyone, I want to sum up the number of ok and error in all column in excel. For column1, the answer should be (1 OK, 1 error) . For column2, the answer should be (2 error). How do I count the column data like this? Can I use Pivot table to do this?

Comment: Yes a pivot table can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the countifs formula. If you want to count the "errors" in column a, you would use the formula =COUNTIFS(A:A,"error")

Answer (score 0):

Change columns names according to yours in formula
[image: Output]